# python: write 'backslash double-quote' string into file

Tags: python, string, encoding

I've got an input file with some string containing double quotes in it, and want to generate a C-style header file with Python.

Say,

```
input file: Hello "Bob"
output file: Hello \"Bob\"
```

I can't write the code to obtain such a file, here's what I've tried so far:

```
key = 'key'
val = 'Hello "Bob"'
buf_list = list()
...
val = val.replace('"', b'\x5c\x22')
# also tried: val = val.replace('"', r'\"')
# also tried: val = val.replace('"', '\\"')
buf_list.append((key + '="' + val + '";\n').encode('utf-8'))
...
for keyval in buf_list:
    lang_file.write(keyval)
lang_file.close()
```

The output file always contains:

```
Hello \\\"Bob\\\"
```

I had no problems writing `\n`, `\t` strings into the output file.

It seems I can only write zero or two backslashes, can someone help please ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape both the double-quote and the backslash. The following works for me (using Python 2.7):

```
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

with open('temp2.txt', 'w') as g:
    g.write(data.replace('\"', '\\\"'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However the kind of strings I have to write to the file are similar to:
    `key = "value with \quotes\""`
and your code will obviously produce:
    `key = \"value with \quotes\"\"`
...Almost there :)

Comment: @maestun you'll need to do some kind of pre-processing to separate out the quotes you don't want to change from the quotes you do want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of string to raw string during replacement should do.

```
a='Hello "Bob"'
print a.replace('"', r'\"')
```

The above will give you:
`Hello \"Bob\"`

Comment: Already tried this, see my code. 
This will work with the 'print' function, but not when writing to a file.

Comment: @maestun - Works fine on my side.

Comment: try this: `key = 'key';
val = 'Hello "Bob"';
buf_list = list();
val = val.replace('"', r'\"');
h=open('temp.txt','w');
h.write(val);
h.close();`

Comment: Indeed ! However, see my reply to @asongtoruin